# RAM - Improving performance on MacBook 13Inch Early 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, performance

What is better option to improve RAM performance eon MacBook 13Inch Early 2011:

Removing the original Apple RAM Memory slots of 2GB each (2 slots - each 2GB) and inserting brand new 2 slots of 4GB each 
OR
adding 2 new slots of 2GB each ?

And, what is the best Non-Apple brand for compatible Memory Slots ?

thank you in advance

Finn

Comment: This question should be asked on the [SE Hardware Recommendation site](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @fsb  Not necessarily.  This is a valid question for this site which has already been asked and answered.

Comment: @allan for my understanding, is it valid because it was already asked & answered, because we shouldn't direct  requests for h/w recommendations to the other site, a combination of those or something different?  I don't want to recommend the other sites if it's not appropriate.

Comment: @fsb In general, if you think the question is better suited for another site, please flag it for mod attention and don't leave a comment. This allows us to *move* a post to another site (instead of having the OP asking the same question twice by cross-posting)

Comment: @fsb - The H/W site is for general recommendations like "what's a good USB microphone for recording podcasts."  This particular question is actually about performance of a Mac using different memory configs.

Answer (score 0):

I have the MacBook 13" Late 2011 and this is what I upgraded to and it works perfectly fine and so much faster!

This set is specifically made to work in Apple MacBooks.

[Crucial 8GB (4GBx2) - Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008LTBIT4)

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have upgraded various Macs (iMac 2012 and MacBook 2013) with Kingston RAM.

Some Kingston RAMs come specfic for Apple (I believe these are standard RAMS going through more thorough testing, selecting those which are closer to the specs).  I've ordered those and never had the slightest problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finn,
Kingston RAM is known to be good for macs. Apple has a webpage where they tell you everything you need to know about what kind of RAM your computer has. If you can't figure out how to install it or need help purchasing it, check out Other World Computing (www.macsales.com). Note that their stuff is overpriced, but their instruction videos are great!
Are you sure your problem is the RAM? I just replaced the hard drive of a 2011 MBP with an SSD and it went much faster (I did a test - it booted three times as fast and opened Microsoft Outlook more than five times as fast. If you don't know that it's your RAM that needs upgrading, try running some tests and consider upgrading to an SSD first.